Sessions of apache webserver expiring - forcing logout of users (non php)
I have got some webservers running behind a proxy-server. These webservers are running an application, but it seems users are getting a 'session expired' error. This error forces a logout and users need to refresh their browser to be able to login again.
Are there any suggestion on what could be done to extend de session lifetime?
Here are some settings I have already adjusted:
PROXY
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/vhosts.conf
<VirtualHost *:443>
       ServerName XXX
       ServerAlias XXX
       SSLEngine On
       SSLCertificateKeyFile /XXX/server.key
       SSLCertificateFile /XXX/WILDCARD.crt
       SSLCertificateChainFile /XXX/WILDCARD.ca-bundle
       SSLProxyEngine On
       ProxyPreserveHost On
       <Proxy *>
               Require all granted
       </Proxy>
       ProxyPass "/" "http://<ip_of_webserver>/"
       ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://<ip_of_webserver>/"
       Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
</VirtualHost>

/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/status.conf
<IfModule mod_status.c>
        # Allow server status reports generated by mod_status,
        # with the URL of http://servername/server-status
        # Uncomment and change the "192.0.2.0/24" to allow access from other hosts.

        <Location /server-status>
                SetHandler server-status
                Require local
                #Require ip 192.0.2.0/24
                ## Added own range
                Require ip IP-range/24
        </Location>

        # Keep track of extended status information for each request
        ExtendedStatus On

        # Determine if mod_status displays the first 63 characters of a request or
        # the last 63, assuming the request itself is greater than 63 chars.
        # Default: Off
        #SeeRequestTail On


        <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
                # Show Proxy LoadBalancer status in mod_status
                ProxyStatus On
        </IfModule>


</IfModule>

/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_event.conf
# event MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestWorkers: maximum number of worker threads
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
#<IfModule mpm_event_module>
#       StartServers                     2
#       MinSpareThreads          25
#       MaxSpareThreads          75
#       ThreadLimit                      64
#       ThreadsPerChild          25
#       MaxRequestWorkers         150
#       MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
#</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet


### Adjusted standard values
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
        StartServers                     5
#       MinSpareThreads          25
#       MaxSpareThreads          75
        ServerLimit     2000
        ThreadLimit                      64
        ThreadsPerChild          25
        MaxRequestWorkers         1500
#       MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

Any ideas on where I can add more exceptions to make a session last longer?

Are you sure Apache is handling the session? Your language (PHP or another) is most probably setting up a Cookie with a limited expiration. Figure out who is setting the cookie and extend it's duration.

Please provide details of the application such as what it is written in.  Maybe part of the cookie handling code

Since an external firm is providing us with the application tools, it is hard to look into what exactly is causing the expiring sessions. Any idea where I can look into? The application is written in Vue. You can check it at https://vlot-intranet.durme.be/webwisad/start.html.

Can you check which cookies are added to requests? You can check that under F12 (dev tools) -> network and then the cookie tab for any request.
